# Insert record into table where ID is hashed?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hash, primary-key

I am trying to insert a record into a table which has two keys: `TableNo int` and `RateID varchar32`.

Both don't allow nulls. The issue I have is if I insert a record from backend using insert into I have to specify a `RateID`, so if I give it 0 or 1 or 3 it works however when I insert record from frontend the system generates a unique 32 character reference. I am trying to recreate this and wondering how the system is generating the unique ID.

This is the code captured from a SQL Server trace;

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'INSERT INTO BTRRTEmpls (TableNo, Employee, EffectiveDate, Rate, RateID) 
VALUES (@TableNo, @Employee, @EffectiveDate, @Rate, @RateID)',
    N'@TableNo int,@Employee varchar(6),@EffectiveDate datetime,@Rate decimal(4,2),@RateID varchar(32)',
    @TableNo=1111,@Employee='781.WM',@EffectiveDate='2020-01-01 
00:00:00',@Rate=45.65,@RateID='A010589973F841C28EB8E4356D0B6CFC'
```

How is this value `A010589973F841C28EB8E4356D0B6CFC` for `@RateID` generated?

[image: Screenshot of Table]

Comment: Check if the RateID column has some constraint that specifies a default value, even if from the capture it seems that the ID is generated by the application itself (and not by SQL Server).

Comment: We can't reverse engineer your front-end from a distance. It might be a hash of the values, it might be a GUID, it might be a custom function. All you know for sure is that the application passes in an `INSERT` statement with this value already specified, so you will learn nothing more from the database.

Comment: RateID does have a constraint ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BTRRTEmpls] ADD  DEFAULT (0) FOR [Rate]
GO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generates a random 32 bit character which is unique

```
REPLACE(NEWID(),'-','')
```